# How to create quiz with PHP?

Tags: php, html

I get some errors when I execute my code to get the string that display my questions and answers in the quiz with php.
com/ZCy6G.jpg

Comment: It would be helpful to know what errors you are receiving...

Comment: so, what do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current version of php doesn't support the javascript style of array literal constructor so I have to use the original style. The code below has minimal styling but seems to output the questions and options correctly.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>quiz</title>
        <style>
            form{ display:block; float:none; width:90%;margin:1rem auto;box-sizing:content-box;padding:1rem;border:1px solid black; }
            ul{}
            li{}
            h3{margin:2remauto 1rem auto;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        $quizHistoryQ = array(
            "Q1" => array(
                "question"=>"This is the First question",
                "options" => array(
                    "this is option 1",
                    "this is option 2",
                    "this is option 3"
                ),
                "answer" =>2
            ),

           "q2" => array(
                "question"=>"This is the Question String for question 2",
                "options" => array(
                    "this is option A",
                    "this is option B",
                    "this is option C"),
                "answer" =>1
            ),

            "q3" =>array(
            "question"=>"This is the Question String for question 3",
            "options" => array(
                "this is option X",
                "this is option Y",
                "this is option Z"
            ),
            "answer" =>0
            )
        );



        echo "
        <form name='quiz' method='post'>";

        foreach( $quizHistoryQ as $index => $arr ){

            $question=$arr['question'];
            $options=$arr['options'];
            $answer=$arr['answer']; 

            echo '<h3>Question: '.$index.': '.$question.'</h3>';
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach( $options as $i => $option ) echo "<li><input type='radio' name='{$index}[]' value='{$i}'/>{$option}";
            echo '</ul>';
        }

        echo "
            <input type='submit' name='sub' value='Submit'/>
        </form>";

    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should think about accepting the answer to show the problem is resolved

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing concerns array to string conversion, which is caused by this line:

```
echo $key . " : " . $value . "<br>";
```

If you var_dump($value) inside that loop, you'll see that $value is sometimes as array, not a string.  You can iterate over the values in the $value array like so:

```
foreach($quizHistoryQ[$keys[$i]] as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . " : ";
    //note:  in OP's specific example, only is_array test is needed.  is_object test can be omitted in this case since we know $value will never be an object
    if (is_array($value) || is_object($value)) {
        foreach($value as $item) {
            echo $item . '<br />';
        }
    } else {
        echo $value . '<br />';
    }
}
```

This tests to see if $value is an array or string.  If it's an array, it loops through it.  Otherwise, it just echo's the string.